# How to start with NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

Hi I need NSIS installer to make patches to a software. Where to start from. I am running on windows 7. Where do I get the NSIS installer and how to start running it. Can any one tell where I can find related material to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are Some of the useful Links which you can refer:

1.[Introduction](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter1.html#)

2.[Tutorail](http://www.pcauthority.com.au/Feature/24263,tutorial-create-a-nsis-install-script.aspx)

3.[Simple Project](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials).

4.[Sample Script](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24187/Creating-an-Installer)

Answer (score 1):

Why not start looking on the [Official page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) of NSIS, where you can find [Tutorials](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aTutorials) and [examples](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aCode_Examples) for more common tasks.

Also, since you are interested in patches, have a look at [this utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsispatchgen/) - it provides the feature of automatic comparing of two directory trees, which is lacking in NSIS.